# RubyMine 4.5: How to drop into a context-aware Rails Console during debugging?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubymine, ruby-debug

How do you drop into a rails console session during, say, a breakpoint pause while debugging in RubyMine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, this is not possible.  The closest I've been able to figure out is this to evaluate context-aware expressions in the debugger: http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/webhelp/evaluating-expressions.html

Comment: For those interested, I ended up just using the 'debugger' gem with pry instead of the built-in breakpoints. So, not built into the IDE, but gets the job done for a context-aware rails console.

Answer (score 1):

You can drop into an existing ruby process by PID with [hijack](https://github.com/ileitch/hijack).